# Wordpress adding strange html code, breaking some page formatting

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am getting this oddball extra `<br>` inserted into this page above the "Affiliate" title/section.  http://londoncapital.biz/affiliate-program/

Using either Firebug or Element Inspector, I still cannot determine where this is coming from.

This is the generated HTML.

```
<div class="entry clearfix">
<div class="two_thirds"></div>
<div class="one_third last" style="text-align: justify;"></div>
<hr class="clear">
<p></p>
<div class="one_third"></div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div class="one_third"></div>
<br> (THIS SEEMS TO BE THE OFFENDING ELEMENT I THINK)
<div class="one_third last"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<br>
```

I have gone over the page coding in WP page itself and and all three of those sections are identical.

What am I missing here? Some errant code in some php file?

UPDATE INFO:  This is the actual code from the WordPress page: http://pastebin.com/pwJbAGdg

I can't paste the whole code here because I'll be here forever trying to clean up the formatting from the paste.

Comment: your tags not well closed

Comment: Show the way you generate this. Are you using a predefined function?

Comment: Can you double check your tags to ensure there are no line breaks or excessive spaces between them? Also, verified site has closing div tags, editing question for clarification.

Comment: This simply looks like you are using a wysiwyg editor to write your pages. Don't.

Comment: @arkascha not a terribly useful answer and I don't.

Comment: @SankalpMishra  The 'way' I generate is it by hitting 'publish' in wordpress.  If I knew 'the way' then I would be able to edit the file that is creating this stupid tag.

Comment: @DavidHoude  This is what I need to know.  WHERE do I look?  I keep looking through random php files but nothing is obvious where to edit.

Comment: @SridharR  If tags are not well closed, I need to know WHERE those tags are being generated from in order to manually edit those php files.

Comment: I think they belong in your template and should use square brackets [one_third]data1[/one_third] [one_third]data2[/one_third]

Comment: Are you using shortcodes?

Comment: @DavidHoude  What is this "they" are you referring to?  And [] are being used.

Comment: @Dre Yes.  I've developed a bit of a bad taste for WP plugin compatibility.  I am actually researching other CMS's right now (ModX Revolution atm) to find something that better suits my needs. For the moment, this is one of two issues (the other I'll deal with after this is fixed).

Comment: Not really an answer but a suggestion: the WP text editor can be a bit  of a pain when it comes to inserting empty `p` tags and breaks, so make sure you delete any empty lines of text while using the default editor. There's a possibility that those line breaks are being added by the shortcodes you are using.Try removing the lines of text with the shortcodes (the ones starting and ending with `[]`) and see if the errant line breaks disappear from the markup. If they do then we know they are coming from the shortcode and can possible solve that problem

Comment: @Dre  Yeah, just removed the blank lines but I can't take out the [] shortcodes or else the whole page will go to hell.  Sigh.  This is so goofy.  Only one stupid thing is ruining this page.  While I will eventually switch completely to using tables only (plugins do a horrible job at this) I was not planning on doing that right this instant.  What doesn't make sense is that I've used this shortcoee on the other 45 pages and THIS is the only one with this errant spacing issue.

Comment: @DragonDon When I suggest removing the shortcodes I only meant temporarily to see if they were adding the line breaks. Looking at the code that you added to Pastebin it seems likely that it is being added by the shortcodes. Confusingly you also seem to be using regular `div` in some locations (line 1, line 4) and shortcodes in others, although this *shouldn't* cause a problem. 1) Have you tried wrapping your columns in rows? A lot of shortcode plugins include support for rows. 2) It looks like you're using the Onyx theme; have you tried contacting their support regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Surely using this stuff in editor is really cool but if you REALLY need it you can just remove spaces, copy this stuff:

```
<div class="entry clearfix"><div class="two_thirds"></div><div class="one_third last" style="text-align: justify;"></div><hr class="clear"><div class="one_third"></div><div class="one_third"></div><div class="one_third last"></div><div class="clear"></div><br>
```

Open Wordpress Super editor and go to TEXT mode - !important

Paste it - should work.

But that's not the best coding sample :)

Comment: That seems like a great answer but the problem is, WHERE does this go?  Which PHP file should I be putting this code in?  index.php? page.php? functions.php? Maybe the plugin php files?  I am absolutely stumped as to figure out where/what is generating that stupid extra line ONLY for that section.

Comment: It seems that the page is "Affiliate Program" and it can be not in PHP but directly in editor - ina admin panel - check it - can you see there some texts? Note that it may differ. If you see then what exactly you get